# AmCharts V4 - What default state does AmCharts use when the hover event is finished?

Tags: amcharts

My goal is to be able to click on a country and fill that polygon background of that country with a specific color.
As soon as I select another country the previous background should revert to the standard color.

How to reproduce the bug: Click on a country on the codepen and then click on another country. Now hover over the first one and it will be still "active".

It does work when I only click on the country, however after hovering over the country it will use the specific color instead of the standard color (just as if it was selected).

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/ms92o/pen/KBXqLO

And here are the specific code snippets which I have created:

I think the problem arises from the state which the country gets after the hover effect is over. I thought that the default state will get used which I have provided a standard fill color.

```
var selectedPolygon;
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
let polygon = ev.target;
if(selectedPolygon) {
 selectedPolygon.defaultState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");
 selectedPolygon.setState('default');
}
polygon.setState('active');
selectedPolygon = polygon;
})

/* Create hover state and set alternative fill color */
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

/* Create active state and set fill different fill color */
var as = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
as.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");
```

So my question is: what state does the polygon have after the hover effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, on hovering out, the sprite returns back to default state.

In this case, the behaviors were unexpected because that custom state, `"active"`, is actually a [reserved name state](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/#Reserved_named_states). It's used when selecting polygons in other charts like you're doing here. Instead of returning to default, it returns to active. To avoid messes between hover, default, and active states, a new state `"hoverActive"` was introduced in [beta.45](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/master/dist/es2015/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta45---2018-08-17).

If we change the state name/key to something else, we'll find the behavior is more expected, so refactoring `"active"` out of your code with some arbitrary key back in we get:

```
var customActiveState = "selectedCountry";
var selectedPolygon;
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  /* NEW: Create an active state and set fill color to red */
  let polygon = ev.target;
  if(selectedPolygon) {
     selectedPolygon.defaultState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");
     selectedPolygon.setState('default');
  }
  polygon.setState(customActiveState);
  selectedPolygon = polygon;
})

/* Create hover state and set alternative fill color */
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

/* Create active state and set fill different fill color */
var as = polygonTemplate.states.create(customActiveState);
as.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");
```

Example: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/477e8a80e09b4bf87128cd72cc082741

But that's not very useful as we lose the red color as soon as we hover out.

So there're some routes we can take, simpler method is how to make use of the reserved active state and get it to work for you, or just manage the defaultState almost just as you've been doing.

Method 1 - Making use of the [`togglable`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygon/#togglable_property) and [`isActive`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygon/#isActive_property) properties of Sprite (which MapPolygons extend).

Once a sprite is togglable, clicking it toggles the active state automatically, so we leave that logic out of the hit event, and just ensure a previously toggled country is detoggled for sure:

```
var selectedPolygon;
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  /* NEW: Create an active state and set fill color to red */
  let polygon = ev.target;
  if(selectedPolygon && selectedPolygon !== polygon) {
     selectedPolygon.isActive = false;
  }
  selectedPolygon = polygon;
})

/* Create hover state and set alternative fill color */
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

/* Create active state and set fill different fill color */
var as = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
as.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");
```

Example: https://codepen.io/notacouch/pen/259c803601ff6f286a294d1477f022ba

Method 2 - Omit the whole custom active state, take the code you already have, and override both the newly-selected polygon's current and its default state's fills (we have to override the current fill, because if you just override the defaultState's fill, you have to wait til you hover out to see it):

```
var selectedPolygon;
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  /* NEW: Create an active state and set fill color to red */
  let polygon = ev.target;
  if(selectedPolygon) {
     selectedPolygon.defaultState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");
     selectedPolygon.setState('default');
  }
  polygon.defaultState.properties.fill = polygon.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");
  selectedPolygon = polygon;
})

/* Create hover state and set alternative fill color */
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");
```

Example: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/67121e27c3c1d50d669bca0ed040f746